# Whitespace diff anomoly in Meld and Perforce (Possibly others)

Tags: regex, diff, perforce, meld

When changing:

```
    }
    else {
```

and similar to:

```
    } else {
```

Perforce and Meld both report this as a change even with all white space changes ignored. Surely this should just count as a whitespace change?

Meld has the following regex to ignore checked:

```
[ \t\r\f\v]*
^[ \t\r\f\v]*
```

Perforce even gives an example in preferences highlighting what it ignored with each setting and it should ignore this.

Any ideas on what I am missing here and how I can make these changes ignored?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're missing a simple space () and a new-line (line feed) character (`\n`).

```
[ \n\t\r\f\v]*
```

Or you can try a simple `\s` (a white-space character), which should cover all of those exactly:
(as per [Python Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html), which [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/help/text-filters.html) links to)

```
\s*
```

Comment: I've tried both suggestions and it still doesn't like it. It highlights the actual brackets in red

Comment: I just tried Meld. It looks to me like the newline support is somewhat broken (on 1.7.4 on Windows). So I don't think I'll be able to help you much further if you're not running Windows, or you could try logging a bug if you are.